# Logic apps trigger history

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app which triggers when a message is received in the Service Bus queue. It works fine but when I look at the trigger history, it shows a lot records with status as "Skipped" even when the logic app is idle. So what are these records?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A status of skipped just indicates that the nothing new was found to fire the logic. If the trigger is getting fired every minute over an hour for example and you only ever had 20 messages, then the logic would only fire 20 times, every other time you should see skipped appear in the trigger history.

Answer (score 0):

[Logic App_WorkFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQyDl.png)
This is the expected behavior. Based on this configuration, the Logic App is scheduled to trigger every 3 minutes and continue with this work flow only if there is any new message arrived in the queue. If there are no messages received in a queue within this 3 minute (i.e. between the each trigger instance), then it will get skipped and further actions in the workflow will not be continued.

Comment: You have not improved on the already accepted answer.